# Buscar una palabra dentro de un registro php

Tags: php, mysql

no se como explicar en el titulo lo que necesito

Estoy intentando hacer consulta SQL para encontrar una palabra dentro de mi tabla

Por ejemplo: Un input donde coloques una palabra y lo busque en toda la tabla.
Esto es facil mediante este php

```html
if ($row['cliente'] == $_POST['inputbuscarcliente'])
```

Lo que necesito ahora, es un operador que en vez de == (que busca una coincidencia), sea un operador que busque una coincidencia pero no exacta.
Ejemplo: yo busco "Pepito" y aunque el registro sea Pepito Santos, me devuelva el resultado.

No se como explicarme mejor

EDITO*

Tengo este form

```html
<form action="buscar-cliente.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Cliente..." name="buscarcliente">
  <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
</form>
```

y dentro de buscar-cliente.php tengo esto:

```html
<?php if ($row['cliente'] == $_POST['buscarcliente']): ?>
 //Aqui muestro el resultado
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Podrías pedirle a `MySQL` que haga el "filtro" en lugar de hacerlo con `PHP`. ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar la consulta que estas haciendo?

Comment: Como dice Marcos, lo sencillo es tener algo así como "SELECT * FROM table WHERE cliente like '%" . $inputbuscarcliente% . "%'";

Comment: Edito la pregunta con mi codigo

Comment: Efectivamente es mejor hacerlo con [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html), pero **no pasando la variable en la consulta SQL**, ya que incurres en una grave vulnerabilidad: **Inyección SQL**. Debes pasar el dato usando consultas preparadas. Si quieres todos los que empiecen por el dato escrito sería: `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE LIKE columna LIKE 'datointroducido%'`, pero como ya decía, no pases el dato introducido en la consulta, pásalo aparte para que no te inyecten código malicioso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes 2 formas de hacerlo, la primera y mas optimizada es en el mismo sql, practicamente todos los motores de bases de datos (MySql, Sql-Server, Oracle, Informix) son compatibles con el comparador "[Like](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)", éste permite hacer comparaciones "inexactas" gracias a los "[Comodines](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)", caracteres especiales que representan un grupo determinado de caracteres. En este caso, utilizaremos el comodín "%" (Que es una cadena de cualquier caracter y cualquier tamaño, pudiendo ser nula) para "Buscar una palabra" dentro de un campo de una tabla, como ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM Personas WHERE Nombre like '%Pepito%'
```

Esto retornara todas las personas con cualquer parte del `Nombre` que coincida con "Pepito", nombres como "Juan Pepito Hernandez", "Pepito Alberto Gonzales", "ErnestoPepitoSinEspacios" y "Gonzales Pepito".

Sin embargo, hay diferencias considerables si alteramos el uso de los comodines de `like`, por ejemplo `like 'Pepito%'` solo retornaría "Pepito Alberto Gonzales", `like '%Pepito'` solo retornaría "Gonzales Pepito".

Por otro lado, algo considerablemente menos optimizado pero que igualmente funciona, es retornar todo el "Record Set" de la tabla, leer cada Row almacenándolas en tu variable `$row` (como creo que ya estas haciendo) y utilizar la función [strpos](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php) en tu `if` de la siguiente manera:

```
if (strpos($row['cliente'] , $_POST['inputbuscarcliente'])){ 
    //Este $row es coincide con el cliente buscado
 }
```

Dado que `strpos` devuelve una posición de carácter en base 1 (si  encuentra la palabra, incluso al principio, devolverá un numero de la posición siendo la inicial 1) o `False` cuando no la encuentre, es suficiente condición para el `if`. Sin embargo, a menos que por otros motivos tengas que recorrer toda la tabla con tu variable `$row` te aconsejo utilizar el `like` al momento de la consulta.

Procura utilizar métodos que impidan el conocido "SQL inject" si piensas concatenar `$_POST['inputbuscarcliente']` dentro del sql, como [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php) o informate mas [aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: podría incrustar una variable en el SQL de esta forma? 'SELECT * FROM avisos WHERE cliente like '%$buscarcliente%'';

Comment: Podrias, pero te recomiendo que sigas métodos que impidan el SQL Inject, te pasé links para que leas, como [ESTE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php).

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma que se tiene en mysql para hacer eso es usar las funciones de búsqueda fulltext: [Fulltext Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).

Básicamente es buscar una espresión dentro de una columna o varias si así se desea:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles
WHERE MATCH (title,body)
AGAINST ('database' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

Recuerda que las columnas de búsqueda tiene que ser de tipo FULLTEXT para que se pueda realizar este proceso.